# update mysql database based on the value in 2 columns

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a MySQL database with 4 columns: `X_coord`, `Y_coord`, `num_pos`, `num_neg`

What I want to do is update the num_pos corresponding to a specific location, stored in array called location where `location[0]` is the `X_coord` and `location[1]` is the `Y_coord`, and I want to do it dynamically like so:

```
sql = "UPDATE sentimentdata SET num_pos = num_pos + 1 WHERE X_coord = '%s' and Y_coord = '%s'"    %    (location[0],location[1])
```

My question is will this `%s` formatting work?

Comment: I should have mentioned, I am using python with mysqldb

Answer (score 0):

yes,it should work...haven't you tried it?
or you can write it like this

```
sql = """UPDATE sentimentdata SET num_pos=num_pos+1 WHERE X_coord=%s and Y_coord=%s"""
cursor.execute(sql,(location[0],location[1]))
```

if location[0]=x and location[1]=y it is equal to:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE sentimentdata SET num_pos=num_pos+1 WHERE X_coord=x and Y_coord=y""")
```